# If the series $\sum_0^\infty a_n$ converges, then so does $\sum_1^\infty \frac{\sqrt{a_n}}{n} $

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

**Problem:**

> Suppose that for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $a_n\in\mathbb{R}$ and $a_n\ge 0$. Given that
>   $$\sum_0^\infty a_n$$
>   converges, show that 
>   $$\sum_1^\infty \frac{\sqrt{a_n}}{n} $$
>   converges.

**Source**: Rudin, *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*, Chapter 3, Exercise 7.

Comment: See [here](http://binarybeta.blogspot.in/2014/07/convergence-sum-implies-convergence-of.html) for a proof.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112579/converging-series-question-prove-that-if-sum-limits-n-1-infty-a-n2-c

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The Cauchy-Schwarz inequality gives 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sqrt{a_n}}{n}\leq \sqrt{\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n}\,\sqrt{\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}}<\infty.$$

Answer (score 24):

We have for all real numbers $2ab\leq a^2+b^2$ hence 
$$0\leq \frac{\sqrt{|a_n|}}n\leq \frac{|a_n|+\frac 1{n^2}}2.$$
Since the series $\sum_n|a_n|$ and $\sum_n\frac 1{n^2}$ are convergent, we get the convergence of $\sum_n\frac{\sqrt{|a_n|}}n$.

Comment: Why do you use absolute value of $a_n$?