# Convergence of $\frac{\sqrt{a_{n}}}{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Can anyone help me with the following question.

- If $a_{n} \geq 0$ and $\sum a_{n}$ converges then how to prove $\sum \frac{\sqrt{a_{n}}}{n}$ converges.

Any idea where to start. My idea was to try using comparison test since $\sqrt{a_{n}} \leq a_{n}$ but it appears that it wouldn't work if $0 \leq a_{n} <1$.

Comment: try to proceed through $$(\sqrt a_n - \frac{1}{n})^2$$ and expanding this to get given series

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/163441/convergent-series-exercise-from-little-rudin

Comment: use the comparison test

Answer (score 12):

$$\Bigl(\sqrt a_n-\frac{1}{n}\Bigr)^2=a_n-2*\frac{\sqrt a_n}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}<a_n+\frac{1}{n^2}.$$

Since all terms are greater than $0$, by the comparison theorem $$\sum_{n=1}^{n=\infty} \Bigl(a_n-2*\frac{\sqrt a_n}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}\Bigr)$$  converges. But we were given that $\sum_{n=1}^{n=\infty} a_n$ converges and we know $\sum_{n=1}^{n=\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}$ converges, so since the sum or difference of convergent series also converges,the series $\sum_{n=1}^{n=\infty} \frac{\sqrt a_n}{n}$ converges.

Answer (score 9):

I agree with Etheory's answer that the Schwarz inequality is the easiest.

There,

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sqrt{a_n}}{n} \leq \sqrt{\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}}<\infty.$$

Answer (score 1):

$S_n < (s_n(1 + 1/2^2 + ...+ 1/n^2))^{1/2}$ by Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. $s_n$ is a convergent sequence and being the partial sum of the series $a_n$ hence bounded above by $K$, and $1 + 1/2^2 + ...1/n^2 < \pi^2/6$. So $S(n)$ being the partial sum of the current series is bounded above by $3K$, and it is an increasing sequence so must converge and we're done.

Comment: Use LaTeX for mathematics here, lest your answer will go mostly unnoticed. After all you're not that new...

Comment: can some one show me how the mathjax works? the step by step download.

Answer (score 1):

It suffices to show that the sequence
$$
s_n=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\sqrt{a_k}}{k}, \quad k\in\mathbb N,
$$
is bounded.  (Since $\{s_n\}$ is increasing, and assuming boundedness, we obtain that
$\{s_n\}$ converges.)

Using Cauchy-Schwarz we get that
$$
s_n^2=\bigg(\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{a_k}{\sqrt{k}}\bigg)^2\le 
\bigg(\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k^2}\bigg)\bigg(\sum_{k=1}^n a_k \bigg)\le \frac{\pi^2}{6}\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k, \tag{1}
$$
since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$. Since the right hand side of $(1)$
is bounded, so is the left hand side, and hence $\{s_n\}$ is bounded and thus convergent.