# Convergence of a series implies another convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Assume that $\sum a_n$ converges and $a_n\geq 0$. Show that $\sum \dfrac{\sqrt{a_n}}{n}$ also converges. I tried using the comparison test but it does not necessarily work since $a_n$ may be less than 1. I think of using the partial summation formula but I cannot see how to make it work. Any help will do. Thanks!

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1048143, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/374392/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/659180/42969 – found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csum%20%5Cdfrac%7B%5Csqrt%7Ba_n%7D%7D%7Bn%7D%24&p=1)

Comment: Martin R thanks!