# Suppose $a_n$ are positive reals and $\sum a_n$ converges .

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Suppose $a_n$ are positive reals and $\sum a_n$ converges .

Does $\sum \frac{\sqrt{a_n}}{\sqrt{n}}$ converge?

Since $a_n$ is convergent , there exists $N_0$ such that $a_n$< $\epsilon$ for n>$N_0$ also

$a_n+a_{n+1}...a_m$ < $\epsilon$ for all n,m > $N_0$

Also, we know $a_n$ < $\sqrt a_n$ for n>$N_0$.

Any counterexample?

How to continue?

Comment: The 'duplicate' is not the same question...

Comment: @DavidP Agreed- I have voted to re-open and have left a corresponding message in the cured chatroom.

Comment: what is the difference between this question and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/163441/if-the-series-sum-0-infty-a-n-converges-then-so-does-sum-1-infty-frac?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @jimjim In that question $\sqrt{a_n}$ is divided by $n$ and not by $\sqrt{n}$.

Comment: The sum is the same since the "$n$" is under the square root.

Comment: @Peter They were talking about a different one which was incorretly identified as a duplicate. The current duplicate was identified afterwards.