# Is it true that $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n}$ is also convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $\{a_n\}_{n = 0}^\infty$ be a sequence of real numbers such that the series $\sum_\limits{n = 0}^\infty |a_n|^2$ is convergent.

Is it true that $\sum_\limits{n = 0}^\infty \dfrac{a_n}{n}$ is also convergent?

**My try**:

Since $\sum_\limits{n = 0}^\infty |a_n|^2$ is convergent,

$$\begin{align}\lim_\limits{n\to \infty} |a_n|^2=0 &\implies \forall \epsilon >0 \quad \exists N\in \mathbb N \quad \forall n>N \quad|a_n|^2<\epsilon \\ &\implies \forall n>N \quad |a_n|<\sqrt \epsilon \\ &\implies -\sqrt\epsilon<a_n<\sqrt \epsilon  \end{align}$$

Hence $\lim _\limits{n\to \infty} \dfrac{a_n}{n}=0$.

Now $S_n=\sum_\limits{i=1}^n \dfrac{a_i}{n}\implies |S_n|\leq \sum_\limits{i=1}^n \dfrac{|a_i|}{n}\leq \sum _{i=1}^n |a_i|$.

Am I heading in the right way or there is any counter-example? How to complete the proof from here?

Please help.

Comment: hint: apply the cauchy-schwarz inequality

Comment: Or of [Converging series question, Prove that if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n^{2}$ converges, then does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {a_n}{n}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/112579).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**hint**: $\left|\dfrac{a_n}{n}\right| \leq \dfrac{1}{2}\left(a_n^2+\dfrac{1}{n^2}\right)$

Comment: Really appreciate your work

Answer (score 1):

$$\left(|a_n|-\frac{1}{n}\right)^2\ge 0\implies|a_n|^2-2\left|\frac{a_n}{n}\right|+\frac{1}{n^2}\ge 0$$
$$\implies \left|\frac{a_n}{n}\right|\le \frac{1}{2}\left(|a_n|^2+\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$