# Proof that $\sum_{n=1}^n a_n^2$ converges implies that $\sum_{n=1}^n \frac{a_n}{n}$ converges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Calculus 1..

couldn't figure that one.

Given $$\sum_{n=1}^n a_n^2$$ **converges**,

**how do i prove that it implies the converges of** $$\sum_{n=1}^n \frac{a_n}{n}$$ ?

Intuitively i thought about comparison test, but i am not given that $a_n$ is positive.

**Thanks!**

Comment: Look up the Cauchy Schwarz inequality.

Comment: we have $\lim \sqrt[n]{a_n^2}<\ell<1$ with root test, then $\lim \sqrt[n]{\dfrac{a_n}{n}}=\sqrt{\dfrac{\sqrt[n]{a_n}^2}{\sqrt[n]{n}^2}}<\ell<1$

Answer (score 0):

Hint.
$$\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{|a_k|}{k}\right)^2\le
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k^2}
\sum_{k=1}^na_k^2$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $\varepsilon>0$. Since both series$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty{a_n}^2\text{ and }\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}$$converge, there is a natural $p$ such that if $m,n\in\mathbb N$ and if $m\geqslant n$, then$$\sum_{k=n}^m{a_k}^2<\varepsilon\text{ and }\sum_{k=n}^m\frac1{k^2}<\varepsilon.$$Therefore$$\left|\sum_{k=n}^m\frac{a_k}k\right|\leqslant\sqrt{\sum_{k=n}^m{a_k}^2}\sqrt{\sum_{k=n}^m\frac1{k^2}}<\sqrt\varepsilon^2=\varepsilon.$$So, your series converges, by Cauchy's convergence test.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112579/converging-series-question-prove-that-if-sum-limits-n-1-infty-a-n2-c

Comment: @GuyFsone I should have guessed it. (No, this is *not* rethorical.)

Comment: I know that is why I senrt it you because I konw you have enough reputation to quickly close this

Comment: @GuyFsone I have already voted to close it.