# Convergence of $\sum \frac{\sqrt{a_n}}{n^r}$, given $\sum a_n$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I'm preparing for the preliminary exam, and some practice problems are all of the same form. One problem is to prove that convergence of $\sum a_n$ where $a_n \geq 0$ implies convergence of $\sum \frac{\sqrt{a_n}}{n}$. I know how to prove that case using Cauchy-Schwarz (or AM-GM) as is discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112579/if-sum-n-1-infty-a-n2-converges-then-so-does-sum-n-1-infty-f). Now I have another problem:

> 1. Suppose $a_n \geq 0$ and the series $\sum a_n$ converges. Prove the series $\sum \frac{\sqrt{a_n}}{n^{2/3}}$ also converges.
> 2. Give an example of a divergent series $\sum a_n$ such that the series $\sum \frac{\sqrt{a_n}}{n^{2/3}}$ converges.

By Abel's test it's easy to see that, in general, convergence at $r$ implies convergence at any $r' > r$.
I'm not sure how to go about it for $r = 2/3$. Maybe it follows from the case $r = 1$ but I don't see how.

Comment: Instead of $\zeta(2)$, use $\zeta(4/3)$.  Basically $\sum\frac{\sqrt{a_n}}{n^{(1/2)+\epsilon}}$ converges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality

$$\left|\sum_{n=1}^N x_ny_n\right|\le \sqrt{\sum_{n=1}^N x_n^2\sum_{n=1}^N y_n^2}$$

to the case for which $x_n=\sqrt{a_n}$ and $y_n=\frac1{n^r}$, we find that

$$\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{\sqrt a_n}{n^r}\le \sqrt{\sum_{n=1}^N a_n \sum_{n=1}^N \frac1{n^{2r}}}\tag1$$

As $N\to \infty$, the first sum on the right-hand side of $(1)$ converges by assumption while the second converges whenever $r>1/2$.  Inasmuch as $2/3>1/2$, the the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sqrt a_n}{n^{2/3}}$ converges.

---

The condition that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges is not a necessary one for the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sqrt a_n}{n^r}$ to converge.   For example, if $a_n=\frac1{n^p}$, $p<1$, then the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sqrt a_n}{n^r}$ converges for $r>1-p/2$.

Answer (score 1):

You can use G.M $\leq$ A.M here too on the numbers $\frac{1}{n^{4/3}}$ and $a_n$.      \

For the second part you can take $a_n=\frac{1}{n}$. \

Use the convergence of $\sum\frac{1}{n^p}$ for $p>1$.